# Loop takes too long to read txt files and create a word count variable in a dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I test run 3 txt files, and it works well to create a variable in a data frame for each file. However, I have around 8,000 txt files.  It takes too long. Is there any way to improve the speed?

Thanks in advance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(pdftools)
library(readtext)

setwd('E:/txt/GEM_TXT_2022')
files <- list.files(path='E:/txt/GEM_TXT_2022', pattern= ".txt")

filelength<-length(files)
word_count.TOTAL<-seq(1,filelength)
word_count.TOTAL<-as.data.frame(word_count.TOTAL)
head(word_count.TOTAL)

for(j in 1:length(files)){
  P1<-readtext(files[j]) %>% 
    str_replace_all("\\t","") %>% #replace tab
    str_replace_all("\n"," ")  %>% #replace line break
    str_replace_all("      "," ")%>% 
    str_replace_all("     "," ")%>% 
    str_replace_all("    "," ")%>% 
    str_replace_all("   "," ")%>% 
    str_replace_all("  "," ")%>% 
    str_replace_all("[:digit:]","")%>%  
    str_replace_all("[:punct:]","")%>%  
    str_trim()
 
  for(i in 1: length(files)){
    word_count.TOTAL[j,]<-str_count(P1)
  }
  
  }
head(word_count.TOTAL)

word_count.TOTAL2<-as.data.frame(word_count.TOTAL)
rownames(word_count.TOTAL2)<-files
 head(word_count.TOTAL2)
```

Comment: Looks like there is an extra after the 2022 `'` in your line `list.files(path='E:/txt/GEM_TXT_2022'', pattern= ".txt")`.

Comment: Thanks. I correct it, but that is not the reason for having a slow process.

Comment: You can replace for loops for *x*apply or map. Check this article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/computation-time-of-loops-for-apply-map/

Comment: I replaced my initial solution with one that makes use of {vroom} for fast textfile access. Please check whether this speeds up the process.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use {[vroom](https://vroom.r-lib.org/)} for fast access to text files, {stringr} for string manipulation and {[tidytext](https://www.tidytextmining.com/index.html)}. Example:

- load packages, set path constants and read in all text files from a source directory:

```
library(vroom)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)

source_path <- 'path/to/your/text/files'
file_names <- list.files(source_path, pattern = '\\.txt')
file_paths <- file.path(source_path, file_names)

all_lines <- vroom(file_paths,
                   delim = '___', ## see comment (1)
                   col_names = 'raw_text',
                   id = 'source_file') ## (2)
```

(1) *make sure to use a delimiter which won't appear in your documents to keep all in one column*

(2) *store file path in column "source_file"*

- do some string cleaning and `unnest` by token (here: word) to create a separate row per word:

```
all_lines <- 
  all_lines |> 
  mutate(raw_text = str_remove_all(raw_text, '[\\d]')) |>
  unnest_tokens(words, raw_text)
```

- group data by source file and count rows to obtain word count per file:

```
all_lines |>
  group_by(source_file) |>
  summarise(word_count = n())
```